# An internal error has occurred. The application may still be initializing or the URL used is invalid

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

When I try opening the dashDB console from Bluemix, I occasionally get the following error message:

```
An internal error has occurred. The application may still be 
initializing or the URL used is invalid. Check the URL and try again. 
For more information, view the server log files.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a cookie caching issue.

1. Get the domain name from the browser window that is displaying the error message.   E.g. `awh-yp-small02.services.dal.bluemix.net`
2. Open cookie page, for example in firefox:

[image]

3. Search for cookies with the **YOUR** domain name from step 1.

[image]

4. Select all those cookies and delete them by clicking the 'Remove Selected' button.

You should be able to launch now.

WARNING: the above worked for me, but use the above advice at your own risk.