# Can't launch dashDB from Cloudant - blank screen

Tags: cloudant, dashdb

Sometimes when I click on the visit warehouse link in Cloudant, I am presented with a blank screen.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging into Bluemix and launching the dashDB instance from the bluemix console.

It is likely that you will encounter [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807255/an-internal-error-has-occurred-the-application-may-still-be-initializing-or-the).  See the answer on that link for the resolution.